# Create an Array of square numbers with a variadic integer as an input in Swift

Tags: swift, func, variadic

I’m new to this and maybe this is a very bad approach, so let me know please.
I want to create an array of integers by a function that use variadic integers as an input and return the square of those integers in an array. But at the end I forced to initialize the return array by a bogus integer which I ended with a [0]. How to eliminate this 0 in my return array and/or what is the correct solution to this problem?
Thanks.

```
func square(numbers: Int...) -> [Int] {
    var x = 0
    var y = [0]
    var counter = 0
    for i in numbers {
        repeat {
            x = i*i
            counter+=1
            y.append(x)
        } while counter == numbers.count
    }
    return y
}
```

Comment: `var y = [Int]()` use this instead of `var y = [0]`

Comment: @jawadAli  oops, that was one of the basics which I didn’t study well. tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**map(_:)**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) on `numbers` to `return` the squares, i.e.

```
func square(numbers: Int...) -> [Int] {
    numbers.map { $0 * $0 }
}
```

There is no need to write the boilerplate code for what *Swift* has already provided.